# How to go from ElementHandle to DOM element

Tags: puppeteer

I'm using `node --inspect-brk` to debug my puppeteer test. I'm trying to figure out why the following isn't working:

```
    let relationshipHeader = await page.waitForXPath(xpath);
    await relationshipHeader.hover();
```

In the test Chrome window console, `$x(xpath)` returns the correct DOM element. But the `hover()` isn't working, so I wonder which DOM element `relationshipHeader` is for.

Can one of the ElementHandle fields tell me which DOM element relationshipHeader is for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_remoteObject.description` appears to be the answer. For example, with this code:

```
    await page.goto("https://google.com");
    let input = await page.waitForSelector("input.gLFyf");
```

input._remoteObject.description is `input.gLFyf.gsfi`. In Chrome developer tools console of test page, `$("input.gLFyf.gsfi")` yields the DOM element.